# Is Thomas Shelby's meeting with Churchill and his connection with Oswald Mosley real or fiction?

Tags: realism, peaky-blinders

In season 5 of *Peaky Blinders*, we saw Thomas Shelby meeting Churchill, and telling him about how he killed a person back in Birmingham. And all the connection and storyline between him and Oswald Mosley, is it real? As in, was there any person in real life who made an assassination attempt on Oswald? Or did Churchill ever ask anyone to wipe out Mosley?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my friend, Jonathan Campbell, who answered this question;

> Thomas Shelby didn't exist, and the real Peaky Blinders were a street gang who folded up decades before the actual show takes place, so no this never happened.
>
> The show is set in an alternate reality where the real gang never collapsed and instead were run by the (fictional) Shelby brothers and grew and thrived.
>
> So no, it's not real. It's all made up.

Source: https://www.quora.com/Is-Thomas-Shelby-meeting-with-Churchill-and-connection-with-Oswald-Mosley-real-or-fiction/answer/Jonathan-Campbell-49

Comment: Stack Exchange promotes proper citation of sources whenever possible.  That means linking to reliable web sites (and also quoting the relevant sections in the body of the answer, to mitigate link-rot.)  Saying "I asked my friend and he said..." isn't much more compelling than just saying what you think without citation.  No offense intended to either you or your friend, of course.  The information you provide may very well be true, but we appreciate sources we can follow up on ourselves, if we're so inclined.

Comment: Source have been added to the question.